# Jmeter non gui URISyntaxException

Tags: jmeter

Using jmeter non-gui I have a jmx file with this parameter:

```
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">172.29.45.119:33187</stringProp>
```

After finish my test the jml file show:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException,Non HTTP response message: Malformed IPv6 address at index 8: http://[172.29.45.119:33187]/
```

Why [] is it added?

Also I have checked to add:

```
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">172.29.45.119</stringProp>
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">33187</stringProp>
```

But It does not work as well

Comment: <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">172.29.45.119</stringProp>
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">33187</stringProp>-did you get URISyntax exception??

Comment: In that case, I get stuck waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445

Comment: Are you able to ping the ip address??

Comment: How about accessing the site using a browser where you run jmeter?

Comment: Yes, both the browser to acces to the site and jmeter are in the same machine

Answer (score 0):

It appears your instance is looking for an IPv6 IP address.

Add this to <jmeter_home>/bin/jmeter file.

Find Variable :

> ARGS="$SERVER $DUMP $HEAP $NEW $SURVIVOR $TENURING $PERM $CLASS_UNLOAD"

And add :

> -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

You will get:

> ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true $SERVER $DUMP $HEAP $NEW $SURVIVOR $TENURING $PERM $CLASS_UNLOAD"